# Excel 2007 can not edit some cell

Tags: excel, cell

Im helping my friend here in the office but I don't know what to do in his problem. The problem is that he can not edit some cell in excel. He downloaded an excel file with a template of a document he needed. He can add in to the other cells and edit some cells but he can not edit some specific cells. I tried to re"Save as" the document but still can't do. I also search about the "Allow editing directly in cells but it is checked. I'm lost here please help. Any help will be much appreciated. TY!

Comment: copy it to another pc running same / different os and try it there.

Comment: What happens if he tries to edit those cells? Is there a pattern to the cells he can't edit? Are any of the worksheets locked/protected?  Are there any macros running?

Comment: I don't think copying it to another PC is a solution even if it solves it. The solution need to be on the main pc. It'll be too hassle if it should be copied to another pc just to edit.

Comment: To edit a cell you need to double click a cell right, but when I double click a specific cell nothing happens. Its like its unclickable something like that.

Comment: I just said to check whether you've got locked/protected cell or if you have some problem with installed office software. Anyway, looks like you've got some locked/protected cells. You can unlock it in this way - https://www.technipages.com/excel-lock-unlock-cells

Answer (score 1):

Go to Review --> unprotect sheet, unprotect it and then edit the cells

Answer (score 1):

Most probably some of your cells contains some specific formula which was protected by the creator of the document. Unprotect the sheet to unlock the cell editing.